# What would have happened if all of Voldemort's Horcruxes were destroyed before he returned to physical body?

Tags: harry-potter

As the question states, if all of Voldemort's Horcruxes were destroyed and only his mangled spirit that flew to Albania remained, could he have returned to physical body?

Comment: I'm quite sure that without his Horcruxes his sprit would not have survived the bounced back Avada Kedavra....

Answer (score 1):

### With the Philosopher's Stone, yes.

It's true that Voldemort would have required a horcrux to survive. Fortunately, he had one. When his Avada Kedavra spell backfired, it split his soul and part of that latched onto Harry.

Yes, I know, *Harry's not a Horcrux*, but the fact remains that a piece of Voldemort's soul survived, so even with the rest of his horcruxes destroyed, he still would have become the spirit we saw in the first book.

Voldemort's entire plan for *Harry Potter and the Philospher/Sorcerer's Stone* was to obtain the stone and use it to produce the **Elixir of Life**. Doing so would allow him to regain a physical body and return to power.

As Dumbledore said (emphasis mine):

> 'Voldemort likes to operate alone, remember. I believe that he would have found the thought of being dependent, even on the Elixir, intolerable. Of course he was prepared to drink it if it would take him out of the horrible part-life to which he was condemned after attacking you, **but only to regain a body**. Thereafter, I am convinced, he intended to continue to rely on his Horcruxes: he would need nothing more, **if only he could regain a human form**. He was already immortal, you see ... or as close to immortal as any man can be.'

Therefore, Voldemort could, in theory, return to his physical body. Having said that, after that plan was foiled by Harry, Voldemort would have been without any real horcruxes and the remaining books would have been very different, what with the diary, ring and locket not needing destroying. Who knows, the Golden Trio may even have had a relatively normal school life.